# How to search for a nested xml element by its tag name

Tags: javascript, xml, npm

I have the following XML string:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="0" width="1440" height="3036">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
    <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
        <android.widget.ScrollView index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.ScrollView" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/grant_singleton" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/grant_dialog" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[37,1017][1403,2102]" displayed="true">
              <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/content_container" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[93,1073][1347,1549]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1136][1263,1465]" displayed="true">
                  <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_icon" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[664,1136][776,1248]" displayed="true" />
                  <android.widget.TextView index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Allow App to send you notifications?" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_message" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1290][1263,1465]" displayed="true" />
                </android.widget.LinearLayout>
              </android.widget.LinearLayout>
              <android.widget.LinearLayout index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[93,1549][1347,2046]" displayed="true">
                <android.widget.Button index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.Button" text="Allow" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1556][1263,1752]" displayed="true" />
                <android.widget.Button index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.Button" text="Don’t allow" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_deny_button" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1766][1263,1962]" displayed="true" />
              </android.widget.LinearLayout>
            </android.widget.LinearLayout>
          </android.widget.LinearLayout>
        </android.widget.ScrollView>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.widget.FrameLayout>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

I am trying to get the `bounds` attribute of the buttons by searching via text = "Allow" or text = "Don't allow".

The XML elements for those buttons are these:

```
<android.widget.Button index="0" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.Button" text="Allow" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_button" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1556][1263,1752]" displayed="true" />
<android.widget.Button index="1" package="com.google.android.permissioncontroller" class="android.widget.Button" text="Don’t allow" resource-id="com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_deny_button" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[177,1766][1263,1962]" displayed="true" />
```

And the expected answer will be either - `[177,1556][1263,1752]` or `[177,1766][1263,1962]`

I have tried `jsdom` but unable to extract these two button elements.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
> const newDom = new jsdom.JSDOM(xstr);
undefined
> const buttons = doms.window.document.querySelectorAll("android.widget.button");
undefined
> buttons.length
0
```

Is there a way to do that using Javascript?

Comment: *"Is there any NPM library that will help me do that?"* Library recommendations are **specifically** off-topic here on SO, see [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) But your question can easily be edited to not ask for a library recommendation. Instead, ask how you can access that information in a _____ environment and change the tags (remove `npm`, add the environment's tag). That is, ask how to do it, not what library to use to do it.

Comment: If you're doing this in a browser, there is not need for any extra packages, you can do it using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

Comment: Hi, I am not using this in a browser. Any other suggestions?